# Vue.js Принудительное обновление компонента vue2-daterange-picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Работаю с Vue2. Использую библиотеку vue2-daterange-picker для выбора диапазона дат. Я добавил в проект мультиязычность. Добавил в поле data реактивную зависимость lang куда я сохраняю текущее значение языка. Когда я делаю смену языка весь проект обновляется, подтягивает соответствующие языковые файлы, переменная lang тоже обновляется и получает значение выбранного языка. Возникла проблема с компонентом data-range-picker. Он ни в какую не хочет динамически обновляться при смене языка. Я пробовал добавить :key="lang" к data-range-picker, но все бес толку. Альтернативный вариант с data-picker, который по умолчанию поддерживает мультиязычность мне не подходит по функционалу. Есть ли способ заставить принудительно обновиться этот компонент?

```
<date-range-picker
        :key="lang"
        ref="picker"
        :opens="opens"
        :locale-data="{ firstDay: 1, format: 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }"
        :minDate="minDate" :maxDate="maxDate"
        :singleDatePicker="singleDatePicker"
        :timePicker="timePicker"
        :timePicker24Hour="timePicker24Hour"
        :showWeekNumbers="showWeekNumbers"
        :showDropdowns="showDropdowns"
        :autoApply="autoApply"
        v-model="dateRange"
        @update="updateValues"
        @toggle="logEvent('event: open', $event)"
        @start-selection="logEvent('event: startSelection', $event)"
        @finish-selection="logEvent('event: finishSelection', $event)"
        :linkedCalendars="linkedCalendars"
        :dateFormat="dateFormat"
>
    <template v-slot:input="picker" style="min-width: 350px;">
        {{ picker.startDate | date }} - {{ picker.endDate | date }}
    </template>
</date-range-picker>
```

Вот моя data

```
 data() {
  return {
    isShow: false,
    lang: this.$i18n._vm.locale
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал два компонента на два языка